# Passing values from ASP.NET to PHP using Cookies

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies

I wanna transfer strings from an ASP.NET page to a PHP page. The following code was suggested by my friend but its not working. Can anybody tell me where the error is at.

**ASP.NET code**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("name");
        cookie.Secure = true;
        cookie.Value = "Joe";
        Response.Redirect("sample.php");
    }
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($client->_cookies);
echo "cookie is ".$client->_cookies["name"][0];
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_COOKIE['name'];
$cookies = getCookies();
$sessionId = $cookies['name'];
?>
```

.

---

*Apart from this is there anyway to pass values from an ASP.NET page to PHP page?*